# How to increase maxquerystringlength and maxquerylength in wcf rest services?

Tags: wcf

I had written this code in wcf service web config file,i had communicating my sql server from android application using this service,i am sending request from android application using httppost method but its showing querystring is beyond the length. Can we increase length by using any other property,because i want to send larger input so that is there any chance to send or else i have to restrict my query string

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
        <configuration>
        <system.web>
                 <httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength="2097151" maxUrlLength="2097151"/>
            </system.web>
        <connectionStrings >
            <add name="DBConnection" connectionString="Integrated Security=true;Data Source=LENOVO\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Order160415" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
          </connectionStrings>
          <system.serviceModel>
            <services>
              <service name="JsonWcfService.GetEmployees" behaviorConfiguration="EmpServiceBehaviour">
                <endpoint address ="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="JsonWcfService.IGetEmployees" behaviorConfiguration="web">
                </endpoint>
                <host>
                  <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost/" />
                  </baseAddresses>
                </host>
              </service>
            </services>

            <behaviors>
              <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="EmpServiceBehaviour">
                  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                </behavior>
              </serviceBehaviors>
              <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="web">
                  <webHttp/>
                </behavior>
              </endpointBehaviors>
            </behaviors>
          </system.serviceModel>
         <system.webServer>
           <security>
             <requestFiltering>
               <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
             </requestFiltering>
           </security>
          </system.webServer>
        </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a binding configuration for the `webHttpBinding` and assign it to the endpoint, just like any other binding.  To do this, add something like the following to your `<system.serviceModel>` section in the config file:

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MyWebHttpBinding" 
             maxBufferPoolSize="2097151"
             maxBufferSize="2097151"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2097151">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2097151" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

I set the values equal to what you set in the `<httpRuntime>` element in your posted config.

The final step is to assign this binding configuration to your service endpoint using the `bindingConfiguration` attribute in the `service` element:

```
<endpoint address="" 
          binding="webHttpBinding" 
          bindingConfiguration="MyWebHttpBinding"
          contract="JsonWcfService.IGetEmployees"
          behaviorConfiguration="web">
```

To sum up:

1. Create a binding configuration definition in the web.config file with the values you want.
2. Assign the binding configuration definition (using the `name` attribute) to the `bindingConfiguration` attribute in the `<service>` element.

In the absence of a binding configuration definition (and its assignment to an endpoint), WCF will use the default values for the binding protocol specified.  In this case, the default values would be 524,288 for `maxBufferSize` and `maxBufferPoolSize`, 65,536 for `maxReceivedMessageSize` and 8,192 for `maxStringContentLength`, which are all smaller than the 2,097,151 limit you set in the `<httpRuntime>` element.

These settings are specific to the WCF service (or client, if it's in the client config), so even if IIS will accept the larger message, WCF will reject it if it exceeds the limits defined by the binding.

For more information, see  on MSDN.